# Handling codeship failures on references which no longer exist

Tags: version-control, codeship

Sometimes I push code to a feature branch, and because of rebasing and git push force the reference no longer exists. However, codeship still tries to download the reference and run its CI on it.

Is there any way (such as a special exit code) to tell CodeShip to neither pass nor fail a build where the reference no longer exists, or to delete it from the build history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's not possible right now. In theory you could force a build to succeed even if tests fail by making sure that those commands return an exit code of zero.

But the `git clone` is a step that's run by Codeship itself and that you can't modify. Because of this and the fact the the exit code of `git clone` is not zero, the step and the build will fail.

I'll bring this up with the team, but I'm not sure if we're going to change the behavior.

*Disclaimer: I'm working for Codeship.*